# Using FILTER or IMPORTRANGE to bring in and filter data from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want to bring in data from a separate sheet and filter it.

I can get IMPORTRANGE to work like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL","A:J)
```

But that doesn't filter. I can only get FILTER to work in the same sheet like this:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:J, C:C="Yes")
```

Is there anyway to bring these two functions together and FILTER data from another spreadsheet into a new sheet, based on column C info?

The reason for doing this is to then use the auto notification setting, so whenever someone enters "yes" into the sheet I can be notified.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `=IMPORTRANGE("URL","A:J")`? (You seem to be missing a quote.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) instead of `filter` for this:

```
=query(importrange("URL","A:J"), "select * where Col3 = 'Yes'")
```

The command `query` can refer to the columns of the array that it receives in an abstract way: Col1, Col2, and so forth, without being tied to their placement within the sheet. So, it filters the thing "in the cloud" and then puts the result into the sheet.

In contrast, `filter` can only refer to columns by the cell names like `C:C`. This means that the array must first be placed into the sheet, and then be filtered in place according to its own values. This runs into circular dependency.

Comment: user 79865 answers is really helpful. Just adding in that you can use the Google Charts query language to modify the query to something different. For example: =query(importrange("URL","A:J"), "select * where (Col3 like '%Yes%')"). Reference document: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en.

Comment: QUERY may have issues when you have mixed data types, like phone numbers in various formats (which is what prevented this from being a solution to one of my problems). See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5599833/query-not-showing-all-phone-numbers?hl=en&msgid=5609677.  Use FILTER instead if that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can bring the two together like so:

```
=filter(IMPORTRANGE("URL","A:J"),INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("URL","A:J"),0,3)="Yes")
```