# FILTER has mismatched range size; referencing the second last cell in a column in range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange, google-sheets-filter

I am using a multicriteria filter to check if my sheet contains a certain value combination. The formula should automatically include any new rows added to the sheet. However, if I do it this way:

```
=IF(FILTER(IMPORTRANGE(Overview!V22, "TabName!D2:F"), 
           IMPORTRANGE(Overview!V22, "TabName!D2:D") = "KI", 
  ISNUMBER(IMPORTRANGE(Overview!V22, "TabName!F2:F"))) = "KI", "KI", "")
```

This is the error I get:

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 162. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

I think the problem is that for the conditions I need to define the range, e.g. F2 to the second last cell in a column but I don't know how to do that within a range definition.

I am really new to this and would appreciate any hints :)

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using FILTER or IMPORTRANGE to bring in and filter data from another spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87272/using-filter-or-importrange-to-bring-in-and-filter-data-from-another-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

#### example for those who need to use `FILTER` formulas and struggle with range mismatch of `FILTER`

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0))

=FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A))

=FILTER(A1:A, ISNA(MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0)))

=FILTER(A1:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A)))
```

in case you need to use `FILTER` formula to return evaluation between two ranges, and those two ranges are of different size (like when they are returned from a query) and can't be altered to match the same size and you just got `FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: etc.` error, then this is a workaround:

to keep it simple let's say your ranges for the filter are **A1:A10** and **B1:B8**, you can use array brackets `{}` to append two virtual rows on range `B1:B8` to match size `A1:A10` by using `REPT`where number of needed repetitions shall be calculated by a simple calculation between initial ranges.

then to this `REPT` formula, we need to add +1 as a correction/failsafe (in a case the difference between two initial ranges is 1), because `REPT` works with a minimum of 2 repetitions. so in a sense, we will need to create a range of `B1:B11` (from `B1:B8`) and laters we will just trim off the last row from a range so it would be `B1:B10` against `A1:A10`. we will use 2 unique symbols for `REPT`

next step would be to wrap `REPT` into `SPLIT` and divide by 2nd unique symbol. then, (based on a further need) this `SPLIT` needs to be wrapped into `TRANSPOSE` (because we want to match column size to column size) and the last step would be to wrap it into `QUERY` and `limit` out the output again by simple math of `COUNTA(A1:A10)` to trim off the last rept cell. put together it would look like this:

```
=FILTER(A1:A10, NOT(COUNTIF(QUERY({B1:B8; 
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀", COUNTA(A1:A10)-COUNTA(B1:B8)+1), "♀"))}, 
 "limit "&COUNTA(A1:A10), 0), A1:A10)))
```

[image]